# Box2D Collision Filtering with Simultaneous Collisions

Tags: javascript, filtering, box2d, collision

I am using Box2DWeb 2.1a, a direct port of Box2DFlash.

I am using contact filters (b2FilterData) by setting the category and mask bits. This works in part, but there is some irritating behaviour that I did not expect. When items that should not collide are also in contact with another object, which they should collide with, these objects will collide with each other too. I do not want this, but cannot find out how to get rid of it.

I created a b2ContactFilter with a ShouldCollide method that is an exact copy of the b2ContactFilter.prototype.ShouldCollide method in order to print out the values of the category and mask bits upon contact. When the erroneous collisions occur, I noticed that the filter1.categoryBits and filter1.maskBits become 0x0001 and 0x65535, respectively. This is as though the b2FilterData is a new instance, or the b2Body has been assigned a new b2FixtureDef instance. I do not know why this has happened, though.

Comment: Can you please share the whole code??

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are assigning the b2FilterData correctly? It should be applied to a b2Fixture and not a b2FixtureDef. If you are doing:

```
var myData = new b2FilterData();
myData.maskBits = ~0x0004;

fixture.m_filter = myData;
```

Try instead:

```
fixture.SetFilterData(myData);
```

If you get an error calling SetFilterData it means you are not calling it on the b2Fixture but on the b2FixtureDef instead, which is wrong.

Did that help at all?

Comment: How do I put objects on different layers so they dont collide with eachother, but collide with the ground?

Comment: @WorstForum That is a new question. If you ask it I can answer for you.

Comment: I'd worked it out - despite the complete lack of documentation for Box2D Web.
 I am, however, pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to find the 50% morph of 2 shapes, so the exact average - using angles / vertices.